# Edit Excel files in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel

We have some document on the server and want to edit thru asp.net application. So a client can login into his account as related excel file will be hosted on a page of asp.net page.

Does anyone know how to edit server document (excel file) in asp.net from the client side.

Comment: File sharing on the server is best suited for sharepoint.

Comment: @Kangkan - I am fraid, it is not. There are far better Document Managment Systems than SharePoint.

Comment: The question is not clear - are you going to have a grid/form in asp.net and based on the entered information you create/modify a file? Or do you want to provide check-in/check-out functionality?

Comment: What exactly "edit" means, is it full excel funcionality or basic CRUD for rows ?

Comment: @Juliusz: I am referring to the MS stable in relation to ASP.NET as in the tag.

Comment: Thanks all. We like to edit files directly like google docs. e.g. on file file1.xls is stored on the server in a folder and user request this file from the asp.net page. that is wanted to be open in page as response. as user changes in that file changes will be submitted to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to edit the Excel file in your code, in the ASP.NET application, then you may try [Aspose.Cells for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/cells/net). This is an API which provides quite flexibility to manipulate Excel files without the need for Microsoft Office to be installed on the server. However, it can only work in the full trust environment, but not a shared hosting environment. Please see if this might help in your scenario. For further details, you may consult the [Aspose.Cells for .NET documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Home).

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: The second link is broken.

Comment: Thanks @HakamFostok,I have fixed the link.